# How to declare n-th order pointers in runtime in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

Pointers can be declared like this:

```
int
    a = 1,
    *b = &a,      // 1st order pointer
    **c = &b,     // 2nd order pointer
    ***d = &c,    // 3rd order pointer
    ****e = &d,   // 4th order pointer
    *****f = &e,  // 5th order pointer
    *** n-stars *** f;  // n-th order pointer
```

Here, we need to know at compile-time the order of the pointer when we are declaring it.
Is it possible at all to declare a pointer, whose order is only known at run time? Linked to this question is whether is it possible to query at run-time the order of an arbitrary pointer?

```
int order = GET_ORDER_OF_PTR(f) // returns 5
int /* insert some syntax here to make ptr a pointer of order (order + 1) */ ptr = &f;
```

**Note**:
I already know this (generally) might not be a good idea. Still want to know if it's doable :)

Comment: Wouldn't that be against the concept of a statically typed language? You could use the type `void*` with an information how often to use the result as another pointer.

Comment: It's potentially against many things

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In runtime you cannot - because C++ is statically typed. During compilation it is possible with templates, e.g.

```
template<typename T, int order> struct P
{
  typedef typename P<T, order-1>::pointer* pointer;
};

template<typename T> struct P<T, 0>
{
  typedef T pointer;
};
```

Then `P<int, 3>::pointer` is equivalent to `int***`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. C++ is statically typed, so the order of a pointer (which is part of its type) must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Not in C or C++ because they're statically typed languages (i.e. the type of the values you store in a variable are known at compile time and fixed).

You can emulate this kind of possibility by defining a C++ class

```
template<typename T>
struct NPtr {
    int order;
    void *p;  // order 0 -> T*, otherwise NPtr<T>*

    NPtr(NPtr *ptr) : islast(ptr->order+1), p(ptr) {}
    NPtr(T *final) : islast(0), ptr(final) {}

    NPtr<T>& nptr() {
        assert(order > 0);
        return *(NPtr<T>*)p;
    }

    T& final() {
        assert(order == 0);
        return *(T*)p;
    }
};
```

A `TPtr<int>` instance can either be a pointer to an integer (when order=0) or a pointer to another `TPtr<int>` instance.

Answer (score 1):

The semantic equivalent of what you want is a linked list, with a number of node determined at runtime:

```
#include <iostream>

union kind_of_pointer
{
  int data;
  kind_of_pointer *next;

  kind_of_pointer(int val) : data(val) {}
  kind_of_pointer(kind_of_pointer* ptr) : next(ptr) {}

  operator int()
  {
    return data;
  }

  kind_of_pointer& operator *()
  {
    return *next;
  }    
};

int     main(void)
{
  kind_of_pointer dyn_ptr{new kind_of_pointer{new kind_of_pointer{new kind_of_pointer{42}}}};
  int***          static_ptr = new int**{new int *{new int{42}}};

  std::cout << ***dyn_ptr << std::endl;
  std::cout << ***static_ptr << std::endl;
}
```

I find this funny, interesting and horrible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
int *f = nullptr;
decltype(f) *newptr = 0;
```

Comment: I dont think it fits the runtime requirement. That being said, I also dont think what OP wants is doable.

Comment: But isn't `decltype` evaluated at compiltime?

Comment: Yes, compile time but I don't see any other way.

Answer (score 0):

> ... we need to know at compile-time the order of the pointer when we are declaring it.

Yes it is **possible at compile time** to determine the order of the pointer type being declared; based on the type (possibly via `typedef`) or the variable, if C++11 can be used (via `decltype()`).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename P>
struct ptr_order
{
  static const int order = 0;
};

template <typename P>
struct ptr_order<P*>
{
  static const int order = ptr_order<P>::order + 1;
};

int main()
{
  typedef int*** pointer;
  cout << ptr_order<pointer>::order << endl; // outputs 3
  // could also use decltype if available...
  // int*** p;
  // ptr_order<decltype(p)>::order is also 3
}
```

The **runtime calculation of the order of the pointer is not possible**, since C++ is statically typed.

Answer (score 0):

As for the

> whether is it possible to query at run-time the order of an arbitrary
>   pointer?

part: no, you most definitely can not, unless you write your own wrapper-class that stores the order of the pointer. Pointer is, basically, a number: the address in memory.

This gives you at least one problem: you can't follow the pointer "all the way through" (which you would have to do to check if the thing your pointer is pointing at is itself a pointer) without potentially causing a segfault or reading "not your application's memory" (which is often prohibited by OS and will cause your application to be aborted; not sure about weather you can prevent this or not).

For example, NULL (or 0) can be cast to *any* pointer type, so is itself a pointer. But does it point to another pointer? Let's find out... BAM! SEGFAULT.

Oh, wait, there's another problem: you can cast (with c-style cast or with reinterpret_cast) pointer of any type to pointer of any other type. So, say, `a` might be pointing to a pointer, but was cast to a different type. Or `a` might have a type of "pointing to a pointer", but actually isn't pointing to one.

P.S. Sorry for using the verb "point" so freely.